# How to icon on hover Image while the color link would also change

Tags: html, css, hover

When a mouse over image or link, how can I have the link change color and picture have a hover effect with the cross icon?

[Fiddle is here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ag1eLdg/3/).

I don't understand how to add the icon.

Comment: I don’t see any special cursor in that fiddle, but anyway: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is confusing.

If you are looking to **change the mouse cursor** (it is currently on 'pointer', which is a hand pointing), then you would update your `.hover-effect` class. Like this:

```
cursor: pointer; /* change this to cursor: crosshair */
```

`crosshair` is the official name of cross icon you mentioned; you can find a variety of cursor styles in the Syntax section of MDN's cursor page (see the edit provided by CBroe).

If you are looking to **change the text link color *and* the image color**, you want to ask a separate question. JavaScript & jQuery (or even CSS) will be able to help you; research those languages for more information.

For now, here's [an updated JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ag1eLdg/8/) which **changes the cursor to crosshair** and **changes the text link color on hover**.

I cleaned up your code because a lot of things are unnecessary. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: I'm  looking to put cross symbol (or two cross lines) over hover layer and on the same time text-link should change color (white to yellow) Exp here http://oi60.tinypic.com/2m4ogux.jpg

Comment: Here you go, let me know if this works for you: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ag1eLdg/10/

Comment: Oh, thank you, that was very helpful, it's almost the desired result. Now the text changes color when mouseover on text and at the same do hover effect on the image. One question: what  I need to change to have hover image effect and at the same time the text changes color  when mouseover on text? http://fiddle.jshell.net/9yce08d2/